# What statistical test to use, Dichotmous IV and DV, with multiple sets of data

Tags: r, regression

I have previously run an experiment relating to a number of measurements from the internet.

I have run the experiment from multiple hosts / participants, multiple times. ie. several sets of data distributed over time per host.

The data I have concerns connections to a collection of hosts conducted in two separate ways. During these connections. A binary event does or does not happen.

I would like to deduce whether the choice of method to connect influences whether the event during the connection happens.

I have already looked at logistic regression models, however I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Please change your title to something more informative.

Comment: And also include some statistical methods tags in addition to r tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multilevel logistic regression is necessary because of the multiple participants and multiple time measures. I am not sure what the model would look like given the few details, but it is a good starting point.

Comment: Would it also be possible to average the results over time allowing for more simplistic analysis through a paired t-test or repeated measures?

That is for a given participant,on average event A happened on N connections?

Comment: If you only want a really rough idea of the results for yourself, you can pooled time measures and see with logistic regression. You will violate many statistical assumptions and pooled different (inter and intra) variances together and potentially bias estimator. If it is for a scientific or commercial purpose, I would go for the appropriate analysis.